# Reading response from proxy using WinHttpQueryHeader()

Tags: winhttp

How to find out if the response is sent from the proxy or end-server by using `WinHttpQueryHeader()` function? I have tried using `WINHTTP_QUERY_PROXY_AUTHENTICATE` as the `dwInfoLevel` paramter to the function `winHttpQueryHeader()` but the buffer I got is NULL.

```
int bufferSize = 0;
char lpOutBuffer[500];

ReturnVal = WinHttpQueryHeader(Handle, WINHTTP_QUERY_PROXY_AUTHENTICATE, NULL, &bufferSize);

ReturnVal= WinHttpQueryHeader(Handle, WINHTTP_QUERY_PROXY_AUTHENTICATE, lpOutBuffer, &bufferSize);
```

`lpOutBuffer` is NULL.

Actually what I think the problem here is that I get the `bufferSize` 0 in the first `WinHttpQueryHeader` and so the second `WinHttpQueryHeader` does not fill the `lpOutBuffer` (since `bufferSize` is 0). Why is the `bufferSize` returned as 0?

Contrary to this, if I use the `InfoLevel` as `WINHTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF`, I do get the correct output and `bufferSize` is not 0, it gets filled after the first `WinHttpQueryHeader()` call..

Answer (score 0):

If a HTTP server requires authentication the HTTP response code is 401 and the corresponding response header is `WWW-Authenticate`. If a proxy server requires authentication the HTTP response code is 407 and the corresponding response header is `Proxy-Authenticate`. I suggest checking the response for the proper HTTP code and then retrieving the corresponding header.

As for the `WINHTTP_QUERY_PROXY_AUTHENTICATE` query flag, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states:

> Retrieves the header that is used to identify the user to a proxy that
>   requires authentication. This header can only be retrieved before the
>   request is sent to the server.

So that particular flag has nothing to do with a response from the server. It is a request header that is sent to identify the user to the proxy.